# Help with TriggerSend in Salesforce Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send

When i call triggerSend API using postman using following reqeust, it throws an error

```
{
    "To": { 
        "Address":"test@email.com",  
        "SubscriberKey":"test@email.com", 
            "ContactAttributes": { 
              "SubscriberAttributes": { 
                    "recipientName":"TestUser",
                    "rejectionReason":{
                        "reasonText":
                            ["Reason One","Reason Two"]
                                      },
                    "referenceNumber":"938439484",
                        "TrackingID":"5464464-3453535-5435335-spatel"
                          } 
                         } 
               }
}
```

Error:

```
{
    "message": "Problem initating message send during deserialization of JSON payload.",
    "errorcode": 10004,
    "documentation": ""
}
```

I have TriggerSend DE created with recipientName, rejectionReason, referenceNumber and TrackingID fields with appropriate type.

Why do I get this error? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to escape your " within rejectionReason

```
"rejectionReason":"{ \"reasonText\": [\"Reason One\",\"Reason Two\"] }"
```

Comment: Thank you EazyE for your response.  I valided JSON without \ and it was valid JSON (https://jsonlint.com/).  So Marketing Cloud does not accept standard valid JSON?

Comment: The issue is that you are trying to insert another JSON object into a field and the field is of a text type. This is causing the error as it is looking at the value there, expecting text and getting an object. You need to turn your object into a string in order to store it inside the field.

Comment: Thank you Gortonington. So only way to use nested JSON structure is to pass as string.  Many other systems are able to accept valid nested JSON structure without passing as string.  Salesforce Marketing Cloud needs some enhancement for TriggerSend API.

Comment: Not quite. You can use nested JSON structures no problem. The issue is that 'rejectionReason' is a field inside a SQL table (DE) and the fileds cannot hold any JSON objects or arrays unless they are stringified.